# Qt Embed QListView in QTableView

Tags: c++, qt

Im trying to display a QListView inside a QTableView so i created a delegate and in the paint event i do

```
QListWidget list;
list.addItem(index.data().toString());
list.addItems({"1", "2", "3", "4"});
list.resize(option.rect.width(), option.rect.height());

painter->save();
painter->setClipRect(option.rect);
painter->translate(option.rect.topLeft());
list.render(painter);
painter->restore();
```

and to get the correct size in sizeHint i do:

```
QListWidget list;
list.addItem(index.data().toString());
list.addItems({"1", "2", "3", "4"});
return list.size();
```

this will render the list but i cant use the scrollbar and the cell size doesnt change to display the complete list. Is there any way to get Qt to render this correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it is hard way to achieve what you want. Just use `setIndexWidget`. For example:

```
QListWidget *list = new QListWidget;
list->addItems({"1", "2", "3", "4"});

QTableView *table = new QTableView;
QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(10,10);
table->setModel(model);
table->setIndexWidget(table->model()->index(0,0), list);
table->resizeRowsToContents();
table->show();
```

In this case, it is complete widget with scrolling support and another features.

**Edit.**

Yes, of course. See another example:

```
QListWidget *list = new QListWidget;
list->addItems({"1", "2", "3", "4"});

QTableView *table = new QTableView;
QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(10,10);

QStandardItem *it1 = new QStandardItem("example1");
QStandardItem *it2 = new QStandardItem("example2");

model->setItem(1,0,it1);
model->setItem(2,0,it2);

table->setModel(model);
table->setIndexWidget(table->model()->index(0,0), list);
table->resizeRowsToContents();
table->show();

for(int i = 0; i < model->rowCount(); i++)
{
    qDebug() << table->model()->index(i,0).data();
}
```

**Output:**

```
QVariant(Invalid) //because it is a widget, there is no data in display role
QVariant(QString, "example1") //our data
QVariant(QString, "example2") 
QVariant(Invalid) //because we didn't set data and so on...
QVariant(Invalid) 
...
```

Comment: if i do that can i also use the data method of my TableView to rtrieve the data from the TableModel? because i want the data in the List to be dependant on the TableModel

Comment: @ACB Why not? Yes, of course! Please see my edited answer.